# What is the relationship between the kernel of a homomorphism and its degree as a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, covering-spaces, spin-geometry, continuous-homomorphisms

Let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a continuous homomorphism between Lie groups (or any appropriate generalization). Is there any relationship between the degree of $\phi$ as a covering map of and the number of elements in its kernel?

The motivation for this question comes from the spin groups: $Pin(s,t)$, $Spin(s,t)$, and $Spin^+(s,t)(s,t)$. If $\lambda$ is the map
$$\lambda: Pin(s,t) \rightarrow O(s,t) \\ u \mapsto R_u$$
where
$$R_u(x) = \begin{cases} -x \quad x \parallel u \\ x \quad x \perp u \end{cases}$$
then $\lambda$ has kernel $\{1, -1\}$. From this fact it somehow follows that $\lambda$ is a double covering of Lie group. I do not see where this conclusion comes from, and I suspect that there might be a relation between the degree of $\phi$ as a covering map of and the number of elements in its kernel but I am not sure.

Is it important that $\phi$ be open as well? Surjectivity is implied since we assume $\phi$ is also a covering map.

Comment: Yes, it is related. There is, e.g. a short exact sequence $$\begin{equation}\label{III} \{1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrowtail SU(2,\mathbb{C}) \twoheadrightarrow SO(3,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{1\} \end{equation}$$ where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the kernel of the covering map that itself can be a bit more complicated as in this case (https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/journey-manifold-su2mathbbc-part/).

Comment: Both the kernel and the covering map are defined using preimages. This naturally leads to some information about the covering map being available by considering the kernel.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think what is unclear to me is that since $\phi$ is a covering map, for any point in $B$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ such that $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is a discrete product of sets (the number of elements in the product is the degree of the covering), and the image of each set in the product under $\phi$ is homeomorphic to $U$. However the kernel does not deal with open sets, instead it is the preimage of a singleton set. This is why I don't see the connection between the kernel and the covering space.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez As many as the degree of the covering.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah I see, so this result follows because for any point in $x \in B$, because $\phi$ is an open cover, $\phi^{-1}(x)$ must have as many elements as the degree of the covering. In particular this also applies to the kernel. So if the kernel has two elements $\phi$ must be a double cover. Is that right?

Comment: One thing about your post puzzles me: a general Lie group homomorphism is *not* a covering map, but you are writing your post as it if *is*.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry I should have not written it with such generality, I had the example of the spin groups in mind.